# How to calculate a percentage from a single table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate the percentage on a transaction table. I can achieve my desired effect if I use views, but with the numbers I am dealing with, something faster would be much preferred.

Table (betID is unique):

```
betID | userID | success  
 1    |  1     |  -1
 2    |  1     |   1
 3    |  2     |  -1
 4    |  3     |   1
```

I want to find the winning percentage for every user. I have a strong feeling that I'm missing something small and will be kicking myself for the answer, but all of the examples I've looked at I can't get to work. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The percentage is the number of successes divided by the number of bets.

The difficult part is counting the number of successes without doing an extra select statement.

The answer is to turn the -1 values into 0 values so that the sum of the successes gives you the number of successes (I'm assuming that a -1 is a loss):

```
select userID, sum(if(success = 1, 1, 0)) / count(*) * 100 as pct  from bets group by userID;
```

Comment: Ah! Genius! Never would have figured out to count it that way.